# Paypal sandbox test account URL?

Tags: url, paypal, paypal-sandbox, laravel-5, paypal-rest-sdk

what is the URL to check the sandbox account details such as balance amount and transaction details etc ?

Last time I could see it but now the link is not working , what is the proper link to go ?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/

Just click on "profile" for the account you want to see details for.

Comment: Yeah , I solved it. What exactly happened is when I tried enter wrong password several times the cookies saved in browser and restrict to enter the site . So then after remove cookies , now working perfectly.